# undefined method `request' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an app structure with nested routes in which a `proposal` belongs to a `request` and a `request` has many `proposals`.

When I execute a `send_proposal` method, I am trying to get it to update the `status` of the `request` to which that `proposal` belongs, but I am getting an error that says `undefined method 'request' for true:TrueClass`.

My route for this method (not that I think it matters) is:

```
put "proposal/:id/send_proposal" => "proposals#send_proposal", as: "send_proposal"
```

Here is my `send_proposal` method, as found in my `proposals_controller`:

```
  def send_proposal
    @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:id])
    ProposalMailer.send_proposal_to_client(@proposal, @proposal.request.user).deliver_now
    @proposal = @proposal.update_attributes(status: "Sent to Client")
    @proposal.request = @proposal.request.update_attributes(archived: "Proposal Sent to Client") <<<<<<<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
    flash[:notice] = "Your proposal has been sent to the client!"
  end
```

I have looked at many SO posts for other `TrueClass` errors, but can't seem to find one with a problem like this.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or help me conceptualize what `TrueClass` errors are generally about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes) is an alias for [`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update):

> **update(attributes)**
>   Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the record, all wrapped in a transaction. If the object is invalid, the saving will fail and `false` will be returned.

and `update` returns `true` or `false` (the documentation could be a lot more explicit about this) not the updated model instance. So this:

```
@proposal = @proposal.update_attributes(status: "Sent to Client")
```

will leave `@proposal` as `true` or `false` and neither of those have an `update_attributes` method.

Your controller method should look more like this:

```
def send_proposal
  #...
  @proposal.update(status: "Sent to Client"))
  @proposal.request.update(archived: "Proposal Sent to Client")
  #...
end
```

You probably want to do some error checking on those two `update` calls too.

Comment: Beautiful!  Worked perfectly and great background info.  Thanks!